# How to use compile GTK in C on Mac OS

Tags: c, gtk

I'm getting started in c and would like to create GUI, so I tied using GTK.

I followed the tutorial they gave on https://www.gtk.org/docs/getting-started/hello-world/ , but when I get to compiling, I get this error:

--libs gtk4`
-bash: pkg-config: command not found
hello-world-gtk.c:2:10: fatal error: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

how do I fix this!!! I downloaded it and everything, but it still doesn't work!

BTW the command used to run is: `gcc main.c -o p1 pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`

not sure if this has anything to do with it.

the main.c is in the desktop, and I made sure to cd to it, so that can't be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that `gtk.h` can't be found in the typical include directory (`/usr/local/include`) or the current directory. Run

```
find /usr/local/include . -name gtk.h
```

to verify you actually have the `gtk.h` file. If you do, you may need to move it. If not, you need to download the file.

Comment: I downloaded the file, but it still comes up with a few errors.

Comment: @CodeWizard777 What sort of errors?

Answer (score 0):

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gtk4/4.12.3/lib/pkgconfig/gtk4-macos.pc

pkg-config --modversion gtk4

gcc test.c -o test.out `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk4`
```

Many tried before get success compile, but still got problem to make CSS work on Monterey

Answer (score 0):

Did u forget the backticks? Try this

```bash
gcc main.c -o p1 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```